# How can I add roles using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, spring-boot, spring-security

I had this problem roles can't added when I'm using angular form whereas JSON test postman register added correctly here in frontend roles always null if someone have an idea how can I solve this issue I'll be glad. 
Thank you in advance

**User.Controller**

```
 @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody RegistrationForm signUpRequest) {
       if (utilisateurRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername())) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Username is already taken!"));
        }

        if (utilisateurRepository.existsByEmail(signUpRequest.getEmail())) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Email is already in use!"));
        }

        Set<String> strRoles = signUpRequest.getRoles();

        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

        if (strRoles == null) {
            Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
            roles.add(userRole);

        } else {
            strRoles.forEach(role -> {
                switch (role) {
                    case "admin":
                        Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(adminRole);

                        break;


                    default:
                        Role aideRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_AIDESOIGNANTE )
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(aideRole);
                }
            });
        }
        // Create new user's account
        Utilisateur user = new Utilisateur(signUpRequest.getUsername(),
                signUpRequest.getEmail(),
                passwordEncoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()), signUpRequest.getTelephone(), roles);

        user.setRoles(roles);
        utilisateurRepository.save(user);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("User registered successfully!"));
    }
```

**Authentication.Service Angular**

```
 register(user): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(AUTH_API + 'signup', {
      username: user.username,
      email: user.email,
      telephone: user.telephone,
      role: user.role,
      password: user.password
    }, httpOptions);
```

**Register.Html**

```
 <div class="form-group">
          <label for="role">Role</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            name="role"
            [(ngModel)]="form.role"
            required
            #role="ngModel"
          />

        </div>
```

**Register.ts**

```
 onSubmit() {
    this.authService.register(this.form).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.isSuccessful = true;
        this.isSignUpFailed = false;
      },
      err => {
        this.errorMessage = err.error.message;
        this.isSignUpFailed = true;
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Who is calling your `register` method? Show the code.

Comment: Here is register component I edit my question you can check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that angular forms is setting a single role and your backend is expecting `roles` (in plural). You can solve it by doing the following:

```js
onSubmit() {
  // use rest operator to get a rest object without role
  const {role, ...rest} = this.form;

  // build userData, containing the role collected above
  // SignUpData is declared on Authentication.service
  const userData: SignUpData = {...rest, roles: [role]};

  // use the userData in your request
  this.authService.register(userData).subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.isSuccessful = true;
      this.isSignUpFailed = false;
    },
    err => {
      this.errorMessage = err.error.message;
      this.isSignUpFailed = true;
    }
  );
}
```

#### Authentication.Service Angular

```js
export interface SignUpData {
  username: string;
  email: string;
  telephone: string;
  roles: string[];
  password: string;
}

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AuthenticationService {

  ...
  register(user: SignUpData): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(AUTH_API + 'signup', user, httpOptions);
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I just fixed the first two lines in my answer. It would give you an error message depending on your typescript configs.

Comment: Role still added as ROLE_USER which is role is null

Comment: That object... `this.form`... is it your control or your data? How are you declaring/using it?

Comment: I declare it as form: any = {};

Comment: What do you have on the browser's devtools? Could you provide the form data?

Comment: Yeah I had all form data except role it become null

Comment: I've just noticed that your `register` method is undoing what I've just done in my answer. I'll fix the register method too.